# Are we going for a public [sharing] tag or for specific [X-sharing] tags?

Tags: discussion, retagging

[image]

We have quite some sharing tags:

- [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [file-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing)
- [connection-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/connection-sharing)
- [screen-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screen-sharing)
- [home-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/home-sharing)
- [internet-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-sharing)
- [web-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-sharing)
- [keyboard-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-sharing)
- [file-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing)

Will we go for the more public [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing) tag?

Or will we split it up in multiple [x-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x-sharing) tags?

Answer (score 4):

These topics are too different to unite them as a single tag. They usually involve networking in some form, but that's it.

[sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing) can make sense if the question doesn't fit in any of the other, more specific tags, so it's not like we really can get rid of it.

We could retag some [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing) questions to a more specific [x-sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x-sharing) when touching up the posts anyway, but **I don't think we need to act here**.

Comment: So, someone could just go through them on a boring day, retagging them along the way and leaving those that can't be retagged alone. And then we could still see whether the rest is also big sharing category we could possible retag or merge too... :)

Comment: @TomWijsman Retagging alone strikes me as too minor for an edit here, since it's *almost* tagged correctly, if rather unspecific. If you combine it with reuploading images, fixing grammar, breaking up a wall of text or whatever else makes sense, it would work. That's what I meant with *touching up the posts*.

Comment: Sure, too busy for a lot of retagging these days anyway.